# Open a Folder in the File Manager by a Python Script

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3

I would like to open a specific folder (not a file) in the file manager by pushing a button in a Tkinter frame. Does anyone know the function?

Comment: This question is a programming question (“how to interact with the UI of another program from within a Python program”) which should be asked elsewhere as it is not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `asynch` :

```
import os 
myfolder="/home/pi/Desktop"

def onMyButtonClick():
     os.system("pcmanfm \"%s\"" % myfolder)
```

For `asynch or ̶s̶y̶n̶c̶h̶` use python `subprocess Popen` :

```
import subprocess

myfolder="/home/pi/Desktop"

def onMyButtonClick():        
    p = subprocess.Popen(["pcmanfm", "%s" % myfolder], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate()
```

[subprocess ref.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

[PCMan File Manager (PCManFM) ref.](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM)

Comment: Thank you very much! The first option works fine